# Passing parameter from MainWindow.cs into CurrentRentWeek.cs then outputting result in MainWindow.cs

Tags: c#, xaml

I'd like to pass a parameter into a method stored in the CurrentRentWeek class and then set CurrentRentWeekTextBlock.Text as the value (rentWeek). Is this possible? If so, how do I go about doing it?

**MainWindow.cs**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CurrentDateTimeTextBlock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        var datecheckObject = new CurrentRentWeek();
        datecheckObject.DateCheck(CurrentRentWeekTextBlock.Text);
    }
```

**CurrentRentWeek.cs**

```
class CurrentRentWeek
{
    private DateTime cRentWeekStart;
    private DateTime cRentWeekEnd;
    private DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

    public void DateCheck(string rentWeek)
    {
        if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
        {
            cRentWeekStart = today.AddDays(-5);
            cRentWeekEnd = today.AddDays(2);
            rentWeek = "Current Rent Week: " + cRentWeekStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " + cRentWeekEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        else
        {
            rentWeek = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `DateCheck` return a string value and thehn set the value using that return value. Try this

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CurrentDateTimeTextBlock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    var datecheckObject = new CurrentRentWeek();
    CurrentRentWeekTextBlock.Text = datecheckObject.DateCheck(CurrentRentWeekTextBlock.Text);
}
```

CurrentRentWeek.cs

```
class CurrentRentWeek
{
    private DateTime cRentWeekStart;
    private DateTime cRentWeekEnd;
    private DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

    public string DateCheck(string rentWeek)
    {
        if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
        {
            cRentWeekStart = today.AddDays(-5);
            cRentWeekEnd = today.AddDays(2);
            rentWeek = "Current Rent Week: " + cRentWeekStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " + cRentWeekEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }
        else
        {
            rentWeek = "";
        }
        return rentWeek;
    }
}
```